# Magento 2.2 ssh commands not executed

Tags: magento2, cli

After a PHP upgrade to 7.1 my ssh (Magento) Commands are not executed anymore...

See picture below

[image]

Comment: Did you update the path in your bash command after the update? If you run php -v   what does it return?

Comment: ea-php-cli Copyright 2017 cPanel, Inc.
PHP 7.1.11 (cli) (built: Nov  7 2017 04:14:15) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v10.0.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.11, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

Comment: Since the php is running it almost sounds like a permissions issue. I'm assuming you installed with a lower version of php then updated. I'm sorry but that is outside of my level of knowledge. Only thing I can think of is to update the file/folder permissions using the php bash and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, permissions seem to be okay (755). In my test they are the same and there the commands are working

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that when i use the whole PHP pad, that it works. So

****/usr/bin/php bin/magento module:status works fine (The stars can be filled in with the exact pad if nescesarry)

Why this is is the next question, i'll keep you informed

UPDATE: It was because of to low memory settings in the new PHP.ini